# NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 error handling

Tags: ios, swift

So here is the error.

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the 
>   server." UserInfo=0x1700f0e00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170255e70 "The 
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 
>   -1004.)", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com/,    NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com/,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, 
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=51, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

It comes up very randomly and only way is to reopen the application so it would load the needed data from the API.

My goal would be that if that error comes up, the `GET` function would be called again. So it would get the data and display it without having to reopen the application.

Comment: can you paste the get request you are making? and how are you handling the error in the request?

Comment: @saroshmirza [link](https://gist.github.com/ipajumets/fdffe7535f66483a1bca98186a7bd85b)

Comment: Could this be a http "not s" error?